# Retrieving information from NSObject

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsobject

I have this class:

```
@interface Item : NSObject {

    NSString *name;
    NSString *description;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *description;

+ (id)ItemWithDescription:(NSString*)description name:(NSString*)name;
```

And I am using the following mutable array to keep a complete list of all the items:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *ItemArray;
```

With the code below, in the .m file, I insert a new element in the array

```
[self.ItemArray addObject: [Item ItemWithDescription: @“aDescription” name: @“aName”]];
```

Till here all is ok, but the problem now is that I don’t know how to extract the element “`description`” (as a NSString) of a desired item in the array (let’s say at position [0]). Anyone knows the right syntax to be used?

Comment: FYI - do not name a property `description`. It causes issues with the `description` method of `NSObject`.

Comment: Also, there is no need to explicitly declare the ivars for the two properties (or use `@synthesize` in the .m file). Find a modern tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Item *item = (Item *)self.ItemArray[0];
NSLog(@"%@", item.description);
```

Comment: FYI - the `(Item *)` cast isn't needed.

Comment: Agreed, it's not necessary. I usually do prefer casting when I know what object to expect.

Comment: Your comment about `description` field is spot-on. I spent once a lot of time trying to debug a problem caused by this.